# Why is the background of my layout white?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have created an app where for an activity I have used a background. When I run the app in my phone I am not able to see the background that I have used but the activity runs properly and when I run the app using the emulator :NEXUS 5, the activity fails to load and the app crashes. 
This is the logcat:

```
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.dexcorp.mondaydiary, PID: 3185
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dexcorp.mondaydiary/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary.ui}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dexcorp.mondaydiary.ui.onCreate(ui.java:21)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dexcorp.mondaydiary.ui.onCreate(ui.java:21) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dexcorp.mondaydiary.ui.onCreate(ui.java:21) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 147456012 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dexcorp.mondaydiary.ui.onCreate(ui.java:21) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-18 15:50:21.031 3185-3185/com.dexcorp.mondaydiary E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This the layout where I used the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: Didn't get you.

Comment: I mean this file codes ; '@drawable/back'

Comment: first try background Color instead of using drawable if  background color works then problem is in your background drawable xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your xml i think your drawable, back is too large.

This type of exception occurred when you have large image, so check if your background image is not to large, if so then change it with other small size image and you are good to go!!

Comment: Thank you it helped.I reduced the size and created the xxdpi,hdpi formats etc. now it works properly.Thanks a lot. But the image in the background is getting a bit blurred.Anyways it will do!

Comment: glad that it helped.